# Terminating app while signing up a new user in QuickBlox from ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, registration, quickblox

While [signing up a new user](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Signing_Up)in QuickBlox from ios applicaqtion with login and Password credentials, the app got crashed and the NSLog console shows the error as below,

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'BaseServiceException',
>   reason: 'You have missed the authorization call. Please insert
>   following code inside your application  [QBRequest
>   createSessionWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]; Before any other code,
>   that uses our service, but after setup credentials.**

```
First throw call stack:(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x038365e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02ca48b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   VideoChat                           0x00028e2f -[QBHTTPConnection generateRequestOperation:forPath:usingMethod:] + 1231
3   VideoChat                           0x00028092 -[QBConnection executeRequest:forPath:usingMethod:] + 162
4   VideoChat                           0x0001b049 +[QBRequest(QBAuth) signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:] + 825
5   VideoChat                           0x0000457d -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 2077
6   UIKit                               0x017ff355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
7   UIKit                               0x017ffb95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
8   UIKit                               0x018043a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
9   UIKit                               0x0181887c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
10  UIKit                               0x01818de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
11  UIKit                               0x01806025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
12  GraphicsServices                    0x03d6b2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
13  GraphicsServices                    0x03d6ae01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
14  CoreFoundation                      0x037b1d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
15  CoreFoundation                      0x037b1a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
16  CoreFoundation                      0x037dc77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
17  CoreFoundation                      0x037dbac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
18  CoreFoundation                      0x037db8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
19  UIKit                               0x01803add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
20  UIKit                               0x01805d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
21  VideoChat                           0x00004cbd main + 141
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x033dc725 start + 0)
```

I'm using the below code to create a new user,

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    // session created
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // handle errors
    NSLog(@"%@", response.error);
}];

QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.password = @"azhhdsf";
user.login = @"dsfgsgf";

// Registration/sign up of User
[QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    // Sign up was successful
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Handle error here
    NSLog(@"error while signing up with QB");
}];
```

I saw an answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593701/756941), but it throws an error, that `delegate:self` was deprecated and need to use the above method `signUp: successBlock:`.

Did anyone face this issue? How to fix this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: bro i m facing an issue in quickblox.

Comment: @Imran, as the answerer mentioned, you have to call the quickblox methods within the session creation success loop.

Comment: having problem while log in as a new user viva code...

Comment: @Imran, Try .... `QBSessionParameters *parameters = [QBSessionParameters new];
    parameters.userLogin = @“My Login”;
    parameters.userPassword = @"My Password";
    
    [QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:parameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
        
        QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
        user.ID = session.userID;
        user.password = @“My Password”;

        [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
        `

Comment: `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:[QBChat instance] selector:@selector(sendPresence) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        
    } errorBlock:[self handleError]];`

Comment: bro imran233113@gmail.com this s my email id... plz send me there so i could contact u bro.. i m doing but getting so many error bro please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63003/discussion-between-imran-and-nazik).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these requests are asynchronous and you can't use it this way.

The right way is to wait until session will be created and then sign up a user:

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    // session created

    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.password = @"azhhdsf";
    user.login = @"dsfgsgf";

    // Registration/sign up of User
    [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        // Sign up was successful
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // Handle error here
        NSLog(@"error while signing up with QB");
    }];
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // handle errors
    NSLog(@"%@", response.error);
}];
```

Comment: it's working thanks, but, the password should contain 8 letters. I stuck on that error for 3 hours. :(

Comment: I couldn't find that. It simply shows the error code 422. NP. It's a nice SDK to work with.

Comment: I have [a doubt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25790016/756941) on this SDk. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Hi Igor Khomenko should i create different session for login user and login chat api???

Comment: Hello @IgorKhomenko I get this error Type 'QBRequest' has no member 'createSessionWithSuccessBlock' and I could account key in the dashboard