# Limiting the amount of sending the presence while integrating Quickblox SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-protocols, quickblox, videochat

Let me try to explain clearly,

I'm using the [QucikBlox SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios) for Video calls between two users. It's working great.

But, I need to send the presence of user to QB server for every 30 seconds.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:[QBChat instance] selector:@selector(sendPresence) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This may consume some network connection data of the user. Is there any way to limit this method call?(I don't know whether I'm explaining correct.If any clarifications - please ask)

Will it affect the video chat, if I don't call this method for every 30 seconds?

Please suggest, I'm new to this SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try set it to 60 or 90. 90 is a max possible value.

Anyway this won't consume any network connection data, because it's a very very small ammount of the data we send here

Comment: Hi Igor, [Chatdidreceivemessage is not getting called while receiving a call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624886/qbchat-didreceivemessage-is-not-getting-called-while-receiving-a-call).