# QBChat didReceiveMessage is not getting called while receiving a call

Tags: ios, xmpp, quickblox, xmppframework, videochat

I'm using Quickblox for voice/video call between two devices.
While receiving a voice/video call from an user, I can see the log below,

```
QBChat/didReceiveMessage: <message xmlns="jabber:client" id="XXX-XXX" to="XXXXX-XXXX@chat.quickblox.com" from="1XXXX20@chat.quickblox.com/Smack" type="qbvideochat_call"><extraParams xmlns=""><callType>1</callType><sessionID>XXXXXXX</sessionID></extraParams></message>
```

The method, `chatDidReceiveCallRequestFromUser` is also being called. I can attend the call. But, `chatDidReceiveMessage` is not getting called.

```
-(void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
{
  NSLog(@"called");
   NSLog(@"message %@",message.description);
}
```

It's not showing anything in log. I need to check the message for some further process. What might be missing here?

I tried it in both iOs 7.1 and 8.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Quickblox mightn't grant access to system messages. Try to use your own QBChatMessage with your custom parameters when calling.